# "works" in " Good works could not save those"

Tags: meaning

> Since the first moment of creation, some souls—the elect—had been
>   destined for eternal bliss and others for eternal torment. **Good works**
>   could not save those whom “predestination” had marked for the infernal
>   fires.
>
> From “The American Pageant” by Thomas A. Bailey

I would like to know why the writer is using "works" instead of "work" here.  As far as I know, "work", when functioning as a countable noun, means books, paintings and music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used countably, "works" normally means books, records, paintings etc. ("works of art"), but the phrase "**good works**" has a [theological meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_works). Here, "works" has the sense of "actions", and is used as a countable plural noun.  You will also often see "good deeds" with the same sense.

Your example has many words which are specific to particular Christian views ("creation", "souls", "eternal bliss/torment", "good works" "predestination", "infernal fire") and as [Bailey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_A._Bailey) is known for his writing style, he is probably ascribing a point of view to Christians.  We'd need more context to help more concretely.